# How to add contentDescription to ListPreference?

Tags: android, listpreference, talkback

How to add contentDescription to ListPreference in android. The contentDescription have to be used in list

I have few times in my preference layout ListPreference wyich looks like this

```
  <ListPreference
        android:entries="@array/entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/entryValues"
        android:key="keylist_1"
        android:title="@string/setting"
        android:layout="@layout/custom_checkbox_preference" />
```

Each use same layout. The layout custom_checkbox_preference looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I need to add to title contentDescription how to access to it?

I try to add to ListPreference:

```
        android:hint="@string/desc_setting"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_setting"
```

but this dont't work. I also cannot add this to custom_checkbox_preference in title textview because it's used by other ListPreferences.